Cannot use import statement outside a module when using gsap scrolltrigger on react
I am trying to install the gsap library and use it in my react project with astro framework. following all the steps to the letter i came to this installation:
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import gsap from 'gsap';
import { ScrollTrigger } from 'gsap/ScrollTrigger';

gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

But as soon as I go to start the development environment I get the error attached in the screenshot.
Cannot use import statement outside a module
Stack Trace
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Developer/Git/bitozzi-scale/node_modules/gsap/ScrollTrigger.js:12
import { Observer, _getTarget, _vertical, _horizontal, _scrollers, _proxies, _getScrollFunc, _getProxyProp, _getVelocityProp } from "./Observer.js";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:77:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1288:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1340:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
    at cjsLoader (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:356:17)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:305:7)
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:218:25)
    at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:329:24)

The error seems to be within node_modules, so I can't figure out why it breaks. Can anyone help me please?  :)
I'm trying to get the animations to work at the gsap scrool

What build tool are you using? And also are you using SSR like nextjs/nuxt  or something?

I use vscode and the last version updated yesterday of nextjs

This error is due to the not usage of ES Modules, so you have to use UMD modules
import { ScrollTrigger } from 'gsap/dist/ScrollTrigger';

